# Access meteor application from public network

Tags: node.js, meteor, portforwarding

I'm building a meteor application that integrates with a external service. This external service sends me a rest request. But I'm not able to receive this request in my mac. I've already made the port forward in router, but even so I'm not able to access my application from public network.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's possible that the app is binding to only the local loopback.  Try something like `BIND_IP=<your_external_ip> meteor run`, replacing the angle brackets with your macs external IP.  Other than that, there shouldn't be anything that would block it, other than a bad network setup.

Comment: I can see my service through http://www.canyouseeme.org/. I put my external ip and meteor port (3000) and I get a suscessfull response. I've made like you said and start my meteor app with BIND_IP with my external ip, and my gateway ip. Both unsuccessful when I try to access throught http://myip:3000

Do you have another tip to help me?

Comment: When I said "your ip", I meant the IP that is assigned to the nic of your mac, not your external network IP assigned on your external WAN port.